# How to convert .dsi extension to .csv file

Tags: csv

I have a bundle of data with the .dsi extension. The data contain customer billing energy. My question is how to convert the .dsi extension into .csv extension. Are there any tools to convert the file? Because I've already googled to get the information, but I didn't get much information. I hope someone can help me in order to convert the files. Thank you in advance!

Below is the image I see when I opened the .dsi file in the notepad. This data is generated from customer billing energy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sypic.png)

Comment: You'll need to tell us which program generated this file. When you open it in notepad, what do you see?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, I've just put a picture as your reference. Hope that can help you. May I know, what is actually .dsi extension is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you instead copy paste that text into your question. It looks like a text export of data.  But it looks really messy. What happens if you try to import into excel as a | seperated file?

Comment: This is just to analyse the file. We won't be using this to import. https://affiliate-program-management.com/how-to-view-shareasale-pipe-delimited-file-excel-columns/#:~:text=Launch%20Microsoft%20Excel%2C%20go%20to,Text%20Import%20Wizard%E2%80%9D%20will%20launch.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.